# regex on phone verification not working - javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

not sure why my regex validation is not working... if I enter a number, it still says that it is an invalid number...why? I am trying to check for invalid numbers, but if I type a number I am getting an error as well.

```js
function validatePhone() {

  var phone = document.getElementById("phone1").value;
  if (phone.length === 0) {
    console.log("phone number is required.");
    producePrompt("Phone number is required.", "messagePrompt", "red");
    return false;
  }

  if (!phone.match(/^[0-9]{10}$/)) {
    producePrompt("Please enter a valid Phone number.", "messagePrompt", "red");
    return false;
  }
  producePrompt("valid Number", "messagePrompt", "green");
  return true;
}

function producePrompt(message, promptLocation, color) {
  document.getElementById(promptLocation).innerHTML = message;
  document.getElementById(promptLocation).style.color = color;
}

function remove_msg() {
  producePrompt(" ", "messagePrompt", "red");
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p>Please enter your phone number below:</p>
  <input type="tel" name="phone1" id="phone1" placeholder="(000)000-0000" onkeyup="validatePhone()" />
  <label for="" id="messagePrompt"></label>
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="send message" onclick="validatePhone()" />
</form>
```

Comment: this regex(/^[0-9]{10}$/) will accept 0000000000 but not (000)000-0000

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression will do the work for the input of format `(###)###-####`

```
 ^\([0-9]{3}\)[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4}$
```

But in general this is not a good idea to restrict users to this very specific format. I suggest you accept multiple versions of the phone number, definitely including only numbers with no other characters such as brackets or hyphens.

Comment: I dont think the issue is the regex... although I suggested an input format on the input box, the idea is to expand my regex to accept other formats, but something still not working...

Comment: @Lucky500 You should provide your expect input/output. I don't think others are on the same page with you.

Comment: When I run the code snipped and enter ten integers, I get the green text `Valid number`. Your code seems to work just fine for 10 integers with no other characters